# Write cron script to open and exit application

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automation, cron

I'm trying to write a script that opens a brand new instance of safari, displays a webpage for 10 minutes, then quits safari.

I think I can follow this [Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1151650/automatically-launch-safari-with-a-certain-url-the-first-time-the-mac-wakes-boot) to do steps 1 & 2 of my goal.

For the "display 10 minutes piece," I wasn't sure how to do that except to schedule a separate cron job to quit safari that executes 10 minutes after the first script.

Any idea on how to write a cron script to quit safari? Or to make this process easier? I'm a newbie at cron and would love to learn more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, the following *commands* can be used in a *shell script* to accomplish what you've expressed.

```
/usr/bin/open -na "/Applications/Safari.app" "https://www.google.com/"
pid=$(/usr/bin/pgrep -xn "Safari")
/bin/sleep 600
/bin/kill $pid
```

**Notes:**

Obviously you'd change the *value* of the **URL** in the `open` *command*.

- `open -na` - Assuming another *instance* of the *target app* is running, opens a new *instance* of the *target app*, and if not, just opens the *target app*.
- `pgrep -xn` - Gets the `pid` of the newest *instance* of the *target app*, so you know which *instance* to terminate.

  - `pid=$(...)` - Command Substitution, `$(command)`, allows the output of a *command* to replace the *command name*. In this case, assigns the `pid` of the *target app* to the *variable* `pid` for use as `$pid` with the `kill` *command*.
- `sleep 600` - Sleeps for 10 minutes.
- `kill $pid` - Terminate the *process* by its `pid`.

<sub>I recommend you read the *manual pages* for `open`, `pgrep`, `sleep` and `kill`. You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**</sub>

---

## `cron` example:

From the *manual page* for `crontab`:

> (Darwin note: Although cron(8) and crontab(5) are officially supported under Darwin, their functionality has been absorbed into launchd(8), which provides a more flexible way of automatically executing commands. See launchctl(1) for more information.)

I'm mentioning this because I personally prefer to use `launchd` over `cron` as it's the preferred method that **Apple** endorses.

If you want to use `cron`, have a look at [Scheduling Jobs With Crontab on macOS](https://medium.com/better-programming/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30) and [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru).

I tested a *shell script* with the above *commands* and triggered it both as a `cronjob` and as a *launch agent* under **macOS Catalina**, and it worked for me as coded.

To create the `crontab`, I did the following in **Terminal**:

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

- I use that instead of just `crontab -e` because I prefer `nano` over the default `vim`.

In `nano` I added the following:

```
30 18 * * * /usr/local/bin/codetest
```

Then pressed **^O** to save and **^X** to close `nano`.

As set, `cron` ran the *job* at 6:30 PM executing the `/usr/local/bin/codetest` and `codetest` had a `#!/bin/zsh` *shebang* and the *commands* above, at the start of this answer, in it.

**Notes:**

I recommend you read the *manual pages* for `cron` and `crontab`. You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

---

From [Scheduling Jobs With Crontab on macOS](https://medium.com/better-programming/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30):

Setting cron jobs requires a specific format.

```
* * * * * command
* - minute (0-59)
* - hour (0-23)
* - day of the month (1-31)
* - month (1-12)
* - day of the week (0-6, 0 is Sunday)
command - command to execute

(from left-to-right)
```

You can also use sites like [Crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru) to generate cron expressions.

---

## `launchd` example:

For `launchd`, have a look at: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

As a *launch agent*, in **Terminal**:

```
cd "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/"
touch com.me.new.instance.safari.plist
open -e com.me.new.instance.safari.plist
```

I then added the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.new.instance.safari</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/codetest</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>18</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>45</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Saved the *document* and then back in **Terminal**:

```bash
launchctl load com.me.new.instance.safari
```

Then at 6:45 PM `launchd` executed the `/usr/local/bin/codetest` *shell script*.

---

**Notes:**

I recommend you read the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`. You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Once loaded, it will automatically load when you login to your account, so you shouldn't need to do it manually again under normal circumstances. To unload it, use the `unload` *subcommand* with the `launchctl` *command*.

After unloading it, you can delete the .`plist` *file*, if/when you want to undo changes you've made to your *system*.

Comment: Wow, fuck me.  This is a Gold Standard answer. +1 seems inadequate, but it's yours.

Comment: Wow just wow. You are a technical god.